# Is it accepted to name a variable like this?

Tags: naming-conventions

How acceptable is to name a variable like that:

```
int Δt = 3;
```

and not:

```
int timeDuration = 3;
```

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, but in general, I think its not too wise as it's not easy to type.  But languages like APL have many weirdo characters

Comment: would not do it. I'd expect to have difficulties to write it on different operating systems and editors. And it probably confuses people without mathematical background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love the Delta character.... However it is only acceptable if this becomes a maintainable standard in your code, so that you or your team knows exactly what it is - and you never mix up notation.

Comment: ohh I see, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to work, but I absolutely would not recommend it in anything other than personal projects.
Things like varying encoding languages (UTF etc) can affect these kind of unicode characters. Also the fact it's confusing to reliably type and not really hugely semantic.

Languages such as PHP have these guidelines for `vars`:

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'